# How does "default" known as a "constraint" in sql?

Tags: sql, constraints

Every constraint in SQL is trying to restrict some kind of illegal input. `FOREIGN KEY`, `UNIQUE`, `CHECK`, etc.
The thing is, `DEFAULT`, as the name suggests, does not restrict the input value, rather, "assigns" the value if it's not provided. So how could it possibly categorised as an "constraint" in SQL?

Comment: because it is. What kind of answer do you expect?

Comment: Care to quote the source where it is so categorized?

Comment: It would restrict implicit `NULL`s from being used as values, hence it is a constraint.

Comment: @Jodrell I'm thinking about language design itself, where you decide about semantic of language symbols.

Comment: I've extended my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `DEFAULT` constraint, constrains the insertion of an implicit `NULL` into a column.

That is one way it called be known as a constraint.

---

However, note that in the [SQL-92 standard grammer](http://savage.net.au/SQL/sql-92.bnf.html#xref-row%20value%20constructor%20element) the 'DEFAULT' column definition element is part of a ["default clause"](http://savage.net.au/SQL/sql-92.bnf.html#column%20definition) and is not referred to as a constraint.

Its referred to as a "constraint" in vendor specific implementations, notably Microsoft SQL Server.

Argument's exist, for and against.

Comment: I believe only implicit `NULL`s would be restricted - explicit `NULL`s would be allowed.

Comment: you can set NULL as Default value for any column also, so it means you cannot prevent null from this, and NOT NULL constraint is specific for this use.

Comment: what about `NOT NULL` constraint.

Answer (score 0):

In general it's all about [data integrity](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191447(v=sql.105).aspx). There are two types of integrity:

1. **data integrity** (about correct values in the columns) and
2. **referential integrity** (about relationships between tables).

So constraints (as MSDN [says](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189862(v=sql.105).aspx)) - let you define the way the Database Engine automatically enforces the **integrity of a database**.

And finally - **default constraint** are a special type of constraint (i.e. special type of data integrity mechanisms) that specify what values are used in a column if you do not specify a value for the column when you insert a row.

In other words **constraint** is just a term that used for defining the mechanisms for ensuring the database integrity. Something like this.